# Mongo Spark connector doesn't connect to the provided uri

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Mongo Spark connector doesn't connect to the provided uri

Currently Im trying to connect to mongo from AWS glue,
Using mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.1.1 with Glue 3.0 and Python 3 to connect.

using the following stuff to set with i the config.

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars.packages','org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.1.1')
conf.set('spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri','mongodb://x.x.x.x/')
conf.set('spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri','mongodb://x.x.x.x/')
conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.collection",'customer')
conf.set("spark.mongodb.read.database",'mydb')
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

and when I'm reading the data

```
df = spark_session.read.format("mongodb").option("database","mydb").option("collection","customer").load()
```

the connector is trying to connect to the localhost and not the x.x.x.x throwing the error

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
```

and here are the cluster setting that it created

```
Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
```

Not sure where I went wrong.